# R postscript() Chinese

Tags: r, postscript

I am trying to setup R postscript () device to display Chinese Characters but with no success.

I am using a Macbook Pro Mountain Lion 10.8.3 with the following R `sessionInfo()` information:

---

```
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03) 
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit) 

locale: 
[1] en_US.UTF-8 

attached base packages: 
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached): 
[1] tools_3.0.0
```

---

The following is my main code

```
postscript("圖9-35plotmath.ps", horizontal = FALSE, height = 6) 
plot(c(-pi, -pi/2, 0, pi/2, pi), 1:5, type = "n", xaxt = "n", main = expression(paste(plain(sin) * phi, "與", plain(cos) * phi)), ylab = expression("sin" * phi), xlab = expression(paste("Phase Angle", phi))) 

axis(side = 1, at = c(-pi, -pi/2, 0, pi/2, pi), labels = expression(-pi, -pi/2, 0, pi/2, pi)) 

for(i in 1:5) 
{ 
    text(-2.5, i, substitute(list(xi, eta) == group("(", list(x, y), ")"), list(x = i, y = i+1))) 
} 

text(-1.7, 5, expression("一階微分"== {f * minute}(x)), adj = 0) 
text(-1.7, 4, expression("二階微分"== {f * second}(x)), adj = 0) 
text(-1.7, 3, pos = 4, expression(hat(beta) == (X^t * X)^{-1} * X^t *y)) 
text(-1.7, 2, pos = 4, expression(bar(x) == sum(frac(x[i], n), i == 1, n))) 
text(-1.7, 1.2, pos = 4, expression(paste(frac(1, sigma*sqrt(2*pi)), " ", plain(e)^{frac(-(x-mu)^2, 2*sigma^2)})), cex = 1.2) 

text(0.5, 4.6, pos = 4, expression(prod(plain(P)(X == k), k = 1, n))) 
text(0.5, 4, pos = 4, expression(integral(f(x)*dx, a,b))) 
text(0.5, 3, pos = 4, expression(union(A[i], i  == 1, n))) 
text(0.5, 2, pos = 4, expression(intersect(A[i], i  == 1, n))) 
text(0.5, 1, pos = 4, expression(lim(f(x), x %->% 0))) 

text(2, 4.5, pos = 4, expression(min(f(x), x > 0))) 
text(1, 3.5, pos = 4, expression(Y == beta[0] + list(beta[1]*X[1], ..., beta[p-1]*X[p-1]))) 
text(1.5, 2.5, pos = 4, expression(S^2 == sqrt(frac(sum((X[i]=bar(x))^2), n-1)))) 
dev.off()
```

The above is not working and the resulting postscript file give [...] for all those Chinese characters.  Then, I tried the following:

Using existing GB1 fonts in postscript(). It gives me a .ps file which cannot be opened by Mac Preview, Ghostscript and Photoshop.

```
postscript("圖9-35plotmath.ps", horizontal = FALSE, height = 6, fonts=c("GB1")) 
plot(c(-pi, -pi/2, 0, pi/2, pi), 1:5, type = "n", xaxt = "n", family = "GB1", main = expression(paste(plain(sin) * phi, "與", plain(cos) * phi)), ylab = expression("sin" * phi), xlab = expression(paste("Phase Angle", phi))) 

...............(omitted) 
text(-1.7, 5, family = "GB1", expression("一階微分"== {f * minute}(x)), adj = 0) 
text(-1.7, 4, family = "GB1", expression("二階微分"== {f * second}(x)), adj = 0) 
..............(omitted)
```

I also try to add some font using CIDFont() but still it gives a .ps file which cannot be opened at all.

```
song = CIDFont("SimSun", "GBK-EUC-H", "GBK", "") 
postscriptFonts(song = song) 
postscript("圖9-35plotmath.ps", horizontal = FALSE, height = 6, family="song") 
plot(c(-pi, -pi/2, 0, pi/2, pi), 1:5, type = "n", xaxt = "n", family = "song", main = expression(paste(plain(sin) * phi, "與", plain(cos) * phi)), ylab = expression("sin" * phi), xlab = expression(paste("Phase Angle", phi))) 

..............(omitted) 

text(-1.7, 5, family = "song", expression("一階微分"== {f * minute}(x)), adj = 0) 
text(-1.7, 4, family = "song", expression("二階微分"== {f * second}(x)), adj = 0) 
.............(omitted)
```

There are no warnings for both methods but the .ps file just cannot be opened.

I find it difficult to understand the fonts and family definition in postscript() where par(family = "SimSun") gives me no issue at all to display and save the followings in pdf() and png() devices.

I need to produce a postscript file for high-quality printing.

Thanks again.

SS

Comment: I think you might have done a better job of reducing this to a simple example.

Comment: the program extract is already the shortest with many details omitted.

Comment: Omission of "details" is an effective way to obscure errors. Please produce code that completes the task or produces errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Paul Murrell and Brian Ripley did it in their [2006 R-News article:](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-2.pdf)

```
 pdf("chinese.pdf", width=3, height=1) 
 grid.text("\u4F60\u597D", y=2/3,
            gp=gpar(fontfamily="CNS1")) 
 grid.text("is 'hello' in (Traditional) Chinese",  y=1/3) 
 dev.off()
```

[image]

Just for the record, the code offered by drammock run in R 3.0.0 on a Mac 10.6.8 produces this when opened in MacGhostView:

[image]

Edit: You can inspect the fonts available to the postscript device with:

```
names(postscriptFonts())
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. but I am looking to use postscript device examples.

Comment: The obvious next step would be to install the proper font, and run the example with the postscript or the cairo_ps device.

Comment: I tried the CIDfont to install SimSun but not successful. If you make it, can you help share the coding? Fonts/Family are quite confusing concepts in postscript() device.

Comment: Were the characters in the pdf output I posted correct glyphs? You should realize that difficulties may lie in whatever viewer you might be using if it doesn't have the same set of installed fonts, right?

Comment: Yes. it shows the same characters. when i replace pdf with postscript, it show this error: Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  family 'CNS1' not included in postscript() device. and the plot only show those English characters

Comment: Thanks. those are the fonts: "serif" "sans" "mono" "AvantGarde"         "Bookman" "Courier" "Helvetica" "Helvetica-Narrow" "NewCenturySchoolbook" "Palatino" "Times" "URWGothic" "URWBookman"           "NimbusMon"  "NimbusSan" "URWHelvetica"  "NimbusSanCond"   "CenturySch" "URWPalladio"  "NimbusRom" "URWTimes" "ComputerModern"       "ComputerModernItalic" "Japan1""Japan1HeiMin"  "Japan1GothicBBB" "Japan1Ryumin" "Korea1" "Korea1deb" "CNS1"  "GB1"

Answer (score 0):

`cairo_ps()` works for me on a Mac, both with base graphics:

```
cairo_ps(filename="foo.eps", family="LiSong Pro")
plot.new()
text(0.5, 0.5, "這是漢字")
dev.off()
```

... and with grid:

```
library(grid)
cairo_ps(filename="foo.eps", family="LiSong Pro")
plot.new()
grid.text("這是漢字")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your method but still no luck to make it. the ps file is created but when I open it, the plot is empty without any Chinese characters. I wonder if there are some other settings?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  I just copied and pasted your exact code, replaced the `postscript()` line with `cairo_ps("圖9-35plotmath.ps", family="LiSong Pro")`, and the chinese characters are showing up for me in the plot title and in the two `text()` calls.

Comment: For the record, I was using an iMac running OSX 10.6.8, with an older version of R (2.15.1), platform x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64

Comment: That might be the reasons. I am using OSX 10.8.3 and R3.0. Actually, I do not like to use new version but just because my old MacBook Pro 2009 screen is cracked. Anyway, let me search some R 3.0 release notes to see what happens. One question, do you create (using CIDFont()) LiSong pro font before executing the commands above? I typed postscriptFonts() and LiSong Pro is not original fonts.

Comment: No.  LiSong Pro is an opentype font.  The cairo_ps() device is not limited to using only postscript fonts.